# How do i check given duration times (00:20:40,1:20:40,00:00:10) is <20sec, >1hour and <10 seconds

Tags: javascript

I am having a field called Duration it contains time like 00:20:40.How do i check given duration times (00:20:40,1:20:40,00:00:10) is  <20sec, >1hour and <10 seconds .I tried the following but didn't work.

```
var time = new Date('00:10:40');
  time.getMinutes();
```

Output will look like:

The given time is <20 minute.Hence i need to check like this

```
if(<20 minutes){...}
```

Comment: split with symbol ':'

Comment: what's the output that you are expecting for the above example... is it 40?

Comment: Any error it shows?

Comment: I want to get the minutes from that.Output is 20minutes

Comment: In `HH:MM:SS`, isn't that right?

Comment: _"Output is 20"_ - that's correct then, isn't it?

Comment: How about `01:20:40`? Is the output still `20`?

Comment: _or_ do you want something like 20,6 ('including' the seconds)? (I didn't do the right maths there, I know)

Comment: You can't have `Date` with only time. You must also provide day month and year. Try `new Date('3/3/3 00:20:40').getMinutes()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toSeconds (duration) {
  const regex = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
  const matched = duration.match(regex);
  const hours = parseInt(matched[1]);
  const minutes = parseInt(matched[2]);
  const seconds = parseInt(matched[3]);
  return (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
}

function toMinutes (duration) {
  const seconds = toSeconds(duration);
  return seconds / 60;
}

function toHours (duration) {
  const minutes = toMinutes(duration);
  return minutes / 60;
}

toSeconds('00:20:40') // 1240
toMinutes('00:20:40') // 20.666666666666668
toMinutes('01:20:40') // 80.66666666666667
toHours('01:20:40') // 1.3444444444444446
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var time = "00:20:40".split(":");
var minutes = time[1];
```

The given string "00:20:40" is not a valid date string and cannot be passed to new Date() as an argument. In this case, you can use the above solution which will split the string and give you an array consisting of [hh, mm, ss] and you will be able to get the minutes at time[1].

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'd really not recommend working with Dates/Times on a string basis...

Comment: You are forgetting that if it's an ISO string, this can have a LOT of problems.

Comment: @Weirdpanda, Jeff, As per his question, "00:20:40" is not a standard date string. It cannot be passed to new Date(). I'm interested in knowing what kind of data it is and where he is getting this data from.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Date Object with Date to use it.

```
var d = new Date("1970-01-01 20:18:02");
document.write(d.getMinutes());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.